# Open browser window using ExternalInterface then write HTML in it

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I can open a new window using `window.open()` in `ExternalInterface.call()` but then I want to be able to write contents to the new window. Since, I cannot get the reference of the window back from `window.open()` call, I am not able to do anything to the window once it is opened.

Please note: I do not have any control over the HTML in which my swf is displayed.

Has anyone been in this situation before?

Update: After a few hours of trial and error I found you can get out of this situation by storing your window reference globally and referring to the same global reference whenever you need to access the new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you store the name of the javascript window reference variable. But, you might want to consider the fact that if you don't have any control over the HTML where the swf is displayed, you can't be sure that the javascript access won't throw a `SecurityError` based on various security policies laid out by the flash team.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to simply present a new webpage from your .swf?  if so, external interface is not required.  you can simply use navigateToURL:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com"), "_blank");
```

however, if you want to make a popup window with a custom size and visibility of the browser toolbar and scrollbars, you can call external interface like this:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available)
   {
   ExternalInterface.call(
                         "window.open",
                         "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
                         "win",
                         "height=200, width=300, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes"
                         );
   }
```

Comment: I AM able to open up the browser window using both - `navigateToURL()` and `ExternalInterface`. My question is how to write contents in it using javascript sent through `ExternalInterface`.